# Multiple onReceive usages lead to duplicated API calls

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

We started using Combine for Networks calls in our Application. The user is supposed to input a code, and we want to validate that code via a network call, then perform actions based on the result of said network call.

To our understanding, if we had a published string variable and used that to lazily create another publisher in which we made the API call, we'd only make API calls every time the string changed.

However, the more SwiftUI views that listen to the publisher via `onReceive`, the more API calls get made. Here's a simplified example:

**View**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ResultBenchmarkViewModel

    @State var one: String = "ONE"
    @State var two: String = "TWO"
    @State var three: String = "THREE"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        
            TextField("INPUT", text: $viewModel.inputString)
        
            Text(one)
                .onReceive(viewModel.inputStringPublisher, perform: { string in
                    one = string
                })
        
            Text(two)
                .onReceive(viewModel.inputStringPublisher, perform: { string in
                    two = string
                })
        
            Text(three)
                .onReceive(viewModel.inputStringPublisher, perform: { string in
                    three = string
                })
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class ResultBenchmarkViewModel: Identifiable, ObservableObject {

    @Published var inputString: String = ""

    lazy var inputStringPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never> = {
    
        return $inputString
            .map { string in
                print("API CALL")
                return string
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }()
}
```

Using `onReceive` three times also prints "API CALL" three times every time the user inputs a character. What we expected to happen was that "API CALL" would only be printed once, since `inputString` only changes once, and then the three views that use `onReceive` would only receive the final result published by the publisher.

A solution we're now implementing is listening to the inputString, making the api call and saving the result to a local published variable, which the views then update according to. However, that seems like boilerplate to me that could be obsolete if we properly implemented the original request.

Could we achieve our expected result with some minor changes to the implementation? Or is there a fundamental misunderstanding of combine/swiftui here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can 'share' the output of a publisher. This is what the Share Publisher is for.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/share()

With the Share Publisher, your `inputStringPublisher` would look like this:

```
lazy var inputStringPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never> = {

    return $inputString
        .map { string in
            print("API CALL")
            return string
        }
        .share()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}()
```

Personally, I would continue to use the published variable solution, as there is more logic in the view model.

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it. We will discuss which solution to keep, but it's good to know the share operator.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `.share` modifier to your `inputStringPublisher`:

```
return $inputString
  .map { string in
    print("API CALL")
    return string
  }
  .share()
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I sadly can only accept one answer, and the other poster came before you. But your answer is also the solution.

Comment: No problem! It was a matter of seconds haha. Glad you found the solution :).